# NSMutableArray with Multipal Dictionaries in UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a array of `arrays` that contains `Dictionary's`. How can i fill my `UITableview` with this array?

```
(
        (
                {
            cost = 150;
            height = 1;
            "room_number" = 1;
            "square_size" = 1;
            title = "VERTICAL BLINDS";
            width = 1;
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            cost = 285;
            height = 1;
            "room_number" = 2;
            "square_size" = 1;
            title = "UPHOLSTERY CLEANING";
            width = 1;
        },
                {
            cost = 375;
            height = 1;
            "room_number" = 2;
            "square_size" = 1;
            title = "MATTRESSES CLEANING";
            width = 1;
        }
    )
)
```

This array above contains 2 elements. the last element has 2 objects

I want the array of array's to be the sections (elements) and the dictionaries (objects) to be the cells. Hope this makes sense.

This is what i have tried.

```
 if (clientDataStruct.roomsArray && indexPath.row < [clientDataStruct.roomsArray count])
    {

        NSMutableArray *fetchedArray= [clientDataStruct.roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary = [fetchedArray objectAtIndex:0];


        [contentLabel setText:[fetchedDictionary valueForKey:@"title"]];


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else{
     [contentLabel setText:@"No Rooms - Please add a room"];   
    }
```

This is what i now get after applying the answer below from iPatel.

[image]

This is what i get after applying the answer from sbarow

[image]

Thanks so much to Ipatel. He helped me solve this with his answer below. And upyours to those who demoted. We are all here to learn!!

Comment: You posted this yesterday didn't you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232818/filling-uitableview-with-nsmutablearray/18232909#18232909 what has changed?

Comment: That array was a array of array. Im now sitting with a new problem. Multipil dictionaries in this array of arrays

Comment: Okay, I think the same still applies. Are you looking to use one of those values in the dictionaries as  title for the section?

Comment: People should read before they demote. So annoying. @sbarrow, thanks for the reply. Yes i can get the array as the titles no prob. But im struggling to split the multipal dictionaries

Comment: 2 Snake Blisken: May be show us what have you tried? As i see you ask similar questions without any tries to solve the problem. This is called Copy-Paste Driven Development

Comment: Not sure what you mean split. Does the last element need to have 2 cells (matching 2 dictionary objects)

Comment: 2 Snake Blisken: This is not what have you tried, this is from the answer of previous question. So you tried nothing

Comment: no, this is what works if it was a single dictionary. But now im faced with 2.

Comment: @sbarrow yes, thats what im trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks, ill try implement that quick and see if it fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with following logic:

```
NSMutableArray* nameArrayForLetter = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
NSString *nameString = [[nameArrayForLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

NSLog(@"%@", nameString);
```

**EDITED :**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{ 
    return firstArray.count; 
} 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    NSMutableArray* nameArrayForLetter = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]; 
    return nameArrayForLetter.count; 
} 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
   NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row]; 
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if(cell == nil) 
   { 
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
   } 

//// write your whole code here ; 

   NSMutableArray* nameArrayForLetter = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]; 
   NSString *nameString = [[nameArrayForLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]; 

    cell.textLabel.text = nameString; 

   return cell; 

}
```

Comment: iPatel, thanks, this sort of worked. But see what its doing (image above ). Thanks

Comment: no still gives me duplicate cells in the last section. AS per my last image above

Comment: @SnakeBlisken..put this code  `NSMutableArray* nameArrayForLetter = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];` in  `NSLog`  and tell me, how it displayed .

Comment: This is what it has in that. But its showing the last image above in the cells (3)`For Ipatel : (
        {
        cost = 375;
        height = 1;
        "room_number" = 2;
        "square_size" = 1;
        title = "MATTRESSES CLEANING";
        width = 1;
    },
        {
        cost = 285;
        height = 1;
        "room_number" = 2;
        "square_size" = 1;
        title = "UPHOLSTERY CLEANING";
        width = 1;
    }
)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35506/discussion-between-ipatel-and-snake-blisken)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are not telling the table view the right number of cells to create. Is your table view only showing one cell as opposed to the two cells? If so ensure you are sending the table view the correct information.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [self.aTableContent count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.aTableContent[section] count];
}
```

Comment: ok this, gave me a better result. See image above. ALmost there. thanks

Comment: The only thing wrong is, its showing 2 MATTRESSES CLEANING, where it should show 1 and a UPHOLSTERY CLEANING

Comment: Okay that means the object that you are selecting is incorrect for the cell. Are you using iPatels code to select the object?

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign a view controller to be the data source and delegate of the table view. Then your view controller needs to return the apropriate values for "number of sections", "title of section" , "number of rows in section" and "cell for row".

In the case of cell for row, you should be creating a single cell, and then returning the same cell over and over but with all of it's properties (text label, etc) replaced each time the method is executed. UITableView has a method you can use to facilitate storing and re-using table view cells.

You can find sample code and detailed descriptions for all of this in Apple's documentation on UITableView.